# In plpsql, I'm trying to return response as JSON

Tags: postgresql

```
IF (skip = 0) THEN
    SELECT COUNT(*) as totalcount
    FROM table1 c
    INNER JOIN table2 n ON n.chapter = c.id
    WHERE c.revision = revisionId
        AND n.data IS NOT NULL
        AND n.type = 'text'
        AND data ILIKE query INTO totalcount;
  END IF;

  response.totalcount := totalcount;
```

How do I return json, like here:

```
{ totalcount: 5, skip: 52, result: [{data: "book1", type: chemistry}, {data: "book2", type: physics}]}
```

Comment: what's the question? how to return from the function? howto assign value? how to convert to json?

Comment: specify postgres version. The toolbox for json differs a lot from 9.2 to 9.6

Comment: i am trying to return "{ totalcount: 5, skip: 52, result: [{data: "book1", type: chemistry}, {data: "book2", type: physics}]}" this response from a function. 

I want to achieve something like this "response.totalcount := totalcount" in plpsql, I am not clear how i achieve it.

Postgress version is 9.5.3.0

Comment: @user6618680 note that's not a valid json. Apart from missing qoutes around object keys, it seems that on `result[n].type` you use variables (or just missing quotes again?). -- Also, what is the type of the plpgsql variable `response`? Is it already in the same structure? If that's the case, you just need to call `row_to_json(response)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it in an outer query and use `to_json`:

```
SELECT to_json(wrap)
FROM (SELECT ...) wrap;
```